How can I enable customer selection on the front-end checkout page in WooCommerce?
I'm running an online store using WooCommerce, and I need to allow store managers or administrators to select an existing customer directly from the front-end while placing an order. Currently, this functionality seems limited to the back-end, but I want it to be available on the checkout page or a custom order form on the front-end.
Key requirements:

Customer selection: Instead of manually entering customer details each time, I need a dropdown or search bar on the checkout page that allows selection from a list of existing customers.
Front-end availability: The feature should be accessible during the front-end ordering process, either on the standard checkout page or a custom-built form.

My attempts:

I've explored various WooCommerce settings, but couldn't find an option for this.
I'm open to using plugins or custom code, but I'm unsure where to start.

*How can I implement this customer selection feature on the front-end? Are there specific plugins or custom code examples that can help achieve this?

1. Add a Customer Dropdown to the Checkout Page
// Admin Customer Selection WooCommerce
function add_customer_selection_field_for_admin()
{
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        $customers = get_users(array('role__in' => array('customer', 'subscriber')));
        echo '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">';
        echo '<label for="customer_selection">' . __('Select Customer') . '</label>';
        echo '<select required name="customer_selection" id="customer_selection">';
        echo '<option value="">' . __('Select a customer') . '</option>';

        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($customer->ID) . '">' . esc_html($customer->display_name . ' (' . $customer->user_email . ')') . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_customer_selection_field_for_admin');

2. Set Checkout Selected Customer to particular order
function assign_order_to_selected_customer($order_id)
{
    if (current_user_can('administrator') && isset($_POST['customer_selection']) && !empty($_POST['customer_selection'])) {
        $customer_id = absint($_POST['customer_selection']);

        if ($customer_id) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', $customer_id);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'assign_order_to_selected_customer');

